# Output of shell command in source block is displayed as table

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

The output of the shell commands is displayed as table.
How can I have it displayed as "simple" lines of text ?

[image]

Comment: Try `:results verbatim`

Comment: thks. Good for me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use `#+begin_shell :results drawer` which wraps the results in a drawer. You can also use `:results raw` but that has some disadvantages: Org mode does not know where the results end, so you cannot delete them with `org-babel-remove-result`.

You can also use a different wrapper, e.g. `#+begin_shell :results drawer :wrap example` will wrap the results in a

```
#+begin_example
...
#_end_example
```

block.

Comment: Thks. Good for to know.

Comment: Great, but can I have this redirect as part of the header, cause I never want any output in a popup buffer;)

Comment: I don't understand your question, but in any case, you should ask it (with all the approriate details) as a new question, not as a comment to an answer for a different question.

Comment: OK, I see you *did* ask the [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/75750/org-babel-bash-results-in-results) separately, it has received an answer and you have accepted it, so everything is good.  You might want to delete your comment now.