# org-babel Bash Results in RESULTS

Tags: org-babel, bash

Often when I issue a bash command, the results opens in a popup buffer, instead of going into the RESULTS drawer. F.ex this command.

```
#+begin_src shell
nc -w 2 -v -z danzinger 8507
#+end_src
```

It opens in a popup buffer

```
Connection to danzinger () 8507 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

If I instead issue a "date" command, the results goes into RESULTS;)

Any pointers?;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(org)Results of Evaluation` for selecting and formatting output.  E.g. (somewhat redundantly):

```
#+begin_src shell :results output verbatim drawer replace
echo "foo bar"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
foo bar
:end:
```

In your case I'm guessing the output that you're seeing in a separate buffer is standard error, so probably just redirect that as part of your command?

```
#+begin_src shell
nc ... 2>&1
#+end_src
```